# How to deal with a long subsection title which has formulae

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

I usually use `subsection` environments to write sub questions for a big question. It usually works well as shown in the first example below. However, I encountered an error for the second example below.

> Error Message: ! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.

I guess the problem is with the formula and the length. Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem, please? Thank you!

**Example 1**

```
\subsection{Proceed with the integration in $L(\mu, \sigma^2_a, \sigma^2)$ to determine the likelihood.}
```

**Example 2**

```
\subsection{Show that the log-likelihood for the data can be written as:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log L &=&  -\frac{N}{2} \log 2 \pi  - \frac{1}{2} m  \log(\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a) - \frac{1}{2} (N-m) \log \sigma^2  \\
&& - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_i \sum_j  (X_{ij} - \mu)^2 + \frac{\sigma^2_a n^2}{2\sigma^2 (\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a)} \sum_i^m (\overline{X}_{i\cdot} - \mu)^2,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\overline{X}_{i\cdot} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_{ij}}{n}$.}
```

Comment: The only reason for this is that you want it **bold** (perhaps a bit larger) and numbered, right? There are better ways of doing this. Also see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) suggesting to avoid the use of `eqnarray`. There are better ways of doing that as well.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your response. Could you suggest me some better ways please?

Comment: Late to the party, but: if this is for an exam, you might check out the `exam` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very elementary example that uses a `question` and `subquestion` environment to set something similar to what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,amsmath}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{subquestion}
\numberwithin{subquestion}{question}
%\renewcommand{\thesubquestion}{.\arabic{subequation}}
\NewEnviron{question}{%
  \refstepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\bfseries \thequestion.\quad%
  \ignorespaces\BODY
}
\NewEnviron{subquestion}{%
  \refstepcounter{subquestion}%
  \noindent\bfseries \thesubquestion.\quad%
  \ignorespaces\BODY
}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Proceed with the integration in $L(\mu, \sigma^2_a, \sigma^2)$ to determine the likelihood.
\end{question}

\bigskip

\begin{subquestion}
Show that the log-likelihood for the data can be written as:
\begin{align*}
  \log L &= -\tfrac{N}{2} \log 2 \pi - \tfrac{1}{2} m \log\bigl(\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a\bigr) - \tfrac{1}{2} (N-m) \log \sigma^2 \\
  &\phantom{{}={}} \quad - \tfrac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_i \sum_j  \bigl(X_{ij} - \mu\bigr)^2 + \frac{\sigma^2_a n^2}{2\sigma^2 (\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a)} 
    \sum_i^m (\overline{X}_{i\cdot} - \mu)^2,
\end{align*}
where $\overline{X}_{i\cdot} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{X_{ij}}{n}$.
\end{subquestion}
\end{document}
```

The use of an environment is not all that important here, and could be replaced with something smaller. However, without the proper context as a whole, this should suffice.

---

Your original problem stemmed from the fact that sectional units contain a movable argument, and your use of big math-like constructions is not wanted in those. However, the use of `\section` and `\subsection` for questions does not provide the same contextual reference as (say) `\question` and `\subquestion`.

Answer (score 4):

I think your posting raises two separate issues: First, how to use bold-math for small formulae inside a sectioning header and second, how to deal with very long sectioning headers that contain complicated math material, such as a two-line equation.

The first issue may be dealt with by loading the `bm` ("bold math") package and encasing the math material in a sectioning header in a `\bm{...}` instruction.

AFAICT, the second issue can only be dealt with satisfactorily by removing the entire two-line equation from the sectioning header and placing it in the body of the text. By the way, the `eqnarray` environment is severely deprecated. It's much better to use an environment such as `align`, provided by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for align* environment
\usepackage{bm}       % for \bm macro
\begin{document}
\section{Two assignments}

\subsection{Proceed with the integration in $\bm{L(\mu, \sigma^2_a, \sigma^2)}$ 
  to determine the likelihood}

\subsection{Show that the log-likelihood function can be written in a specific form}

Show that the log-likelihood function can be written as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \log L &=  -\frac{N}{2} \log 2 \pi  - \frac{1}{2} m  \log(\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a) 
      - \frac{1}{2} (N-m) \log \sigma^2  \\
    &\qquad - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_i \sum_j  (X_{ij} - \mu)^2 + 
      \frac{\sigma^2_a n^2}{2\sigma^2 (\sigma^2 + n \sigma^2_a)} 
      \sum_i^m (\bar{X}_{i\cdot} - \mu)^2,
\end{align*}
where $\bar{X}_{i\cdot} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}$.
\end{document}
```